# Office add-in is not displayed on Powerpoint application in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, powerpoint

I have an office add-in that runs on all Office apps (word, excel and powerpoint) in all browsers. But, I have an issue with the IE 11 (not edge). When I load the add-in in powerpoint, I see a message saying that everything went OK, but I do not see the add-in in the taskbar. In the console, I see the following error message:

`invokeVirtualOsfControlActivationCallback failed. Exception details: {"description":"Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\nParameter name: index","name":"Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException","paramName":"index","stack":"Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\nParameter name: index\n   at wac_g.prototype.K (https://powerpoint.officeapps.live.com/pods/ppt.aspx?wdPodsUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpowerpoint.officeapps.live.com%2Fpods%2F&wdPopsUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpowerpoint.officeapps.live.com%2F&fastBoot=true&sw=1696&sh=864&thPanel=917&ro=false&sftc=1&NoAuth=1&fileName=Presentation.pptx&wdoverrides=devicepixelratio:1,RenderGifSlideShow:true&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&mscc=1&wdFR=1&wdOrigin=AuthPrompt&postMessageToken=90A9779F-2005-B000-A241-9DE0B3036003&wdEnableRoaming=1&wdODB=1&fs=27603&hid=90A9779F-2005-B000-A241-9DE0B3036003&usid=57bcf048-901c-2728-b70a-bb7def4ffc8c&fileGetUrlBool=true:85:418)\n`

Is this because IE 11 no longer supports web apps?

Comment: Can the add-in work well in word and excel in IE 11? Which line of code does the error point to? As IE 11 does not support JavaScript versions later than ES5, it will cause errors if you use ES6+ syntax in the add-in. So you can also check if you have used such syntax or some HTML5 features such as media, recording, and location which are not supported by IE 11.

Comment: Yu Zhoo, the add-in works fine in both word and excel app. The only problem is with the powerpoint app
Actually, you can easily test this. Create a powerpoint add-in and try to use it in IE 11. You won't be able to use it!

Comment: I make a test and I can reproduce the issue in powerpoint in IE. I can add the add-ins but  they don't show in powerpoint in IE. I haven't find any official announcement about not supporting powerpoint add-ins in IE. I think there might be some issue with powerpoint and you can provide a feedback in powerpoint.